# How to create custom DbRefs in Spring Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, parse-platform, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to support a MongoDB database originally created by a parse.com installation.
I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data. The problem is that parse.com and Spring Data have different implementations of DB references:

**parse.com**

```
_p_meal_ : { Meal$eh0662S2wn }
_p_FIELD_ : { <REF_CLASS>$<REF_ID> }  // generically
```

**[Spring Data follows the recommendation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/database-references/#dbrefs)**

```
meal: { "$ref" : "meals", "$id" : ObjectId("5126bc054aed4daf9e2ab772"), "$db" : "maindb" }
FIELD: { "$ref": REF_CLASS, "$id": ID, "$db": DATABASE } // generically
```

I want to configure Spring Data so it knows how to read&write DB references the same way as parse.com.
I suspect it has to do with providing a custom `DbRefResolver` to `MongoTemplate` but I'm not sure.

Thanks